# Soft Reset in handyTerminal device with WindowsCE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

Soft reset in WindowsCE Handydevice  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenNETCF framework](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx) provides a simple method for this task:

```
using OpenNETCF.WindowsCE;   
// ... 
PowerManagement.SoftReset();
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, From where will I get the OpenNETCF Dll

Comment: I linked the project webpage. You can download the community edition there.